# No output is shown

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I made a frame and showing a JOptionPane on click of a button but my code is compiling but not generating any output.

I copy the JOptionPane content from -how to make Dialogs blog.

Here is my code:

No output is shown on screen.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DialogDemo extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton btnNext =null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JFrame frame = null;

    public DialogDemo() {
        initialize();


    }
    public void initialize() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(600, 335, 200, 150);
        getContentPane();
        getBtnNext().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
            }
        });
    }
    public JPanel getContentPane() {
        if (contentPane == null) {
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            contentPane.add(getBtnNext());
        }
        return contentPane;
    }

    public JButton getBtnNext() {
        if (btnNext == null) {
            btnNext = new JButton("Next");
            btnNext.setBounds(20, 50, 150, 25);
        }
        return btnNext;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DialogDemo dd=new DialogDemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set visibility of frame to true :)

```
setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set it visible.

Add this line:

`setVisible(true);`.

Without this, not frame will be displayed.